# Is there a more efficient way to da an AVX(2) scatter than the following code generated by gcc?

Tags: intrinsics, avx, scatter, avx2

What is the most efficient way to scatter 8x32 bit floats in a AVX2 register A to memory locations indexed by another (8x32 bit integers) AVX2 register IDX ?

gcc compiles the straight forward implementation into a sequence of shuffle/extract/movss instructions (see attached assembler listing)

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++) array[IDX[i]] = A[i];
```

[image]

My question is: can this be improved by hand coded intrinsics/assembly ?
Note: I am aware that SIMD gather/scatter performance is normall masked/limited by memory bandwith, but here the assumption is, that all data resides in the L1 or L2 cache

Comment: Post code as text, not an image.

Comment: Did you forget to enable AVX2 for vectorization, or tuning options that tell it scatters are efficient (like `-march=skylake`), so it might use `vscatterdps` on its own?  Or maybe the possibility of conflicts (`IDX[i] == IDX[j]`) is making it avoid a scatter instruction, since the C has a well-defined result in that case, but in asm "the elements may be scattered in any order".  Yeah, that would do it, making it not profitable vectorize that C source for just 1 vector worth of data.  (If that is your real C source.)

Comment: Oh wait a minute, derp, scatter stores are AVX-512, not AVX2.  AVX2 only has gather loads.  Sorry.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vscatterdps:vscatterdpd:vscatterqps:vscatterqpd

Comment: GCC's sequence of shuffles could maybe be optimized to get data out of vector registers in 64-bit chunks, or just store/reload even though that would mean more pressure on load ports (shared with store-AGU) when you're already doing a lot of stores.  It already needs lots of port5 uops for the shuffles.  Some of those could maybe be `psrlq ymm, 32` integer shifts that can run on a different port.

Comment: [scatter] is supposed to be about scatter *plots*, but there's already a [scatter-plots] tag.  Hrm, they should either get synonymized (@CodyGray?) or [scatter] repurposed.  But SIMD or GPU scatter stores probably aren't the most likely usage for the term.

Comment: The most efficient way to implement this really depends on the context (and the target CPU). Ideally, you don't need to scatter at all, e.g., if `0<=IDX[i]<8` you could permute inside the vector. If `IDX` is actually larger than 8, but a bijective mapping, it could make sense to invert it and use gather instead of scatter (depends on how often you use it).